# Installing windows on late 2009 iMac 27"

Tags: windows, imac, bootcamp, startup

I've sucessfully installed Win 7 x64 twice on my imac before. However the 2009 iMacs had faulty HDD, I had it replaced and after that I have trouble installing windows. I know about the display drivers needed to be present during install, I have those but I'm still presented with a black screen with blinking cursor while booting Windows - the Windows logo doesn't show.

Found out in mutiple threads that running these:

```
Bootrec.exe /FixMbr
Bootrec.exe /FixBoot
Bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

will fix my booting but I'm unable to get into the repair windows section from the Windows installation disc. It tells me that my verions of Windows is not supported with the disc I have. Found out that it's like that and if I disable other HDDs from bios to make it work, but macs don't have BIOS.
Is there any other way to execute these commands? Did 5 windows reinstalls already without sucess. I'm pretty desperate.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Ran across this: http://ww3.tbreak.com/forums/topic/65304-boot-camp-repair-win7-partition-which-c ant-boot-anymore/

Does anyone know if this is what I should do? Would that let me get into windows repair? I never used terminal commands, ever. Don't want to get into this unless it's what fixes my problem for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what helped me. via http://ww3.tbreak.com/forums/topic/65304-boot-camp-repair-win7-partition-which-cant-boot-anymore/

> Posting this because it was a huge problem that has basically slowed
>   down my work schedule by two days...
>
> Here's the scenario: You've created a new Boot Camp partition, or
>   created a new NTFS partition on your hard disk using a third party app
>   such as TUXERA NTFS-3G for use with your Boot Camp windows install.
>   You restart your Mac and... BAM! No Windows anymore!
>
> What happened??
>
> Basically whatever normal operation you did before in creating a new
>   partition has resulted in the MBR (Master Boot Record, which handles
>   Windows booting) being corrupted. So how do you fix something related
>   to PC when you're on a Mac?
>
> Before you start: First, make sure you can boot properly into Mac OS
>   X. In Mac OS X, in System Preferences, select Startup Disks option.
>   Choose your Mac OS X drive as the startup drive. You can press the
>   restart button to test and see that the setting is saved. Second,
>   uninstall rEFIt if you have it installed as it overrides Single User
>   mode which is required for this fix. Third, if you have TUXERA NTFS-3G
>   installed, disable it. Once you have disabled it, unmount and then
>   remount your Boot Camp partition. This is so that the Boot Camp
>   partition loads with Apple's native drivers rather than Tuxera's weird
>   drivers (which are only useful within Mac OS X). Fourth, keep your
>   Windows 7 install disc handy, you will need it. Don't look at your
>   easy and convenient Windows 7 install USB flash drive, that won't work
>   with a Mac.
>
> - Shut down your Mac
> - While holding down the "Command" and "S" keys, power on the Mac
> - Keep holding down these keys till you see a black DOS-like screen with
>     white text
> - wait till you get a # mark allowing you to type commands
> - type in **fdisk -u /dev/rdisk0** and press enter
> - If asked to create a new
>     MBR, press **y**
> - once the operation is complete type **exit**
> - Wait till it
>     boots to Mac OS X
> - Insert your Windows 7 Installation DVD and restart
>     your Mac
> - After the Mac booting chime, pres and hold the Option key
> - You
>     should get options to select Mac OSX, another hard disk or the Windows
>     DVD
> - Select the Windows DVD
> - Now you're in Windows land. Wait till it's
>     done loading.
> - On the Setup screen where it shows options for language
>     etc. press the Next button
> - In the second screen click the "Repair Your
>     Computer" button
> - This brings you to a dialog where you are to select
>     your windows install. **If you don't see anything listed, don't worry.**
>     Select the radio button related to recovery tools and pres next.
> - You
>     will get a window with links to several tools. Select "Startup Repair"
> - If the operation completes and asks you to restart, click Finish
> - Keep
>     the Windows 7 DVD in the drive, boot into Windows 7 setup again.
> - Navigate to the Recovery Tools section again, This time click on the
>     Command Prompt option.
> - Type in **bootrec.exe /fixmbr**, hit Enter.
> - Type in
>     **bootrec.exe /fixboot**, hit Enter.
> - Restart your Mac.
>
> Pulled this off after 13 hours of browsing through Terminal commands
>   and Mac minutea. There goes the weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the refit boot loader for Macs?  Maybe there is something out of sync with the partition table on your drive (e.g. making new partitions on MacOS that did not sync into Windows or something).  The refit tool has an option to check and sync the HD, and you can choose which partition to boot from ... maybe that fixes something.

Comment: Thanks for taking time, but that wasn't of much help. Going to answer the question with what helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: Well it was worth a try :-)